# Only printing a line after the for loop is done (C++)

Tags: c++, loops

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this piece of code cout the message after the for loop is done. I keeps doing it after every loop. I have multiple for loops checking if a function is increasing/decreasing/non-decreasing/non-increasing. I'm only going to post the increasing one because they're all having the same problem.

I've tried it this way:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            if(val[i] < val[i+1])
            {
                 cout << "Function is increasing!" << endl;
            }

    }
```

And with a counter but I'm pretty sure I used the counter wrong.

Comment: its not clear what should be the output. Do you maybe want to print "Function is increasing" if this is the case for all `i` ?

Comment: yes  that is what its supposed to do @tobi303

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple state machine: check that all points verify your condition. If they do, print something.

```
bool increasing = true;
for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    increasing &= val[i] < val[i+1];
}
if (increasing)
{
    std::cout << "Function is increasing!\n";
}
```

Comment: You should break within the for loop or use `for(i = 0; i < n && increasing; i++)` so it doesn't continue to check if one has already been shown to be false.

Comment: @Goodies One should do a lot to improve the answer. Imporoving the question for a start :D But yes, I agree with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could juste create a variable to save the state of the function:

```
enum State {
Increasing,
Decreasing,
NonDecreasing,
NonIncreasing
} state;
```

and set it correctly in your loop

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
        if(val[i] < val[i+1])
        {
             state = State::Increasing;
        }

}

switch(state) {
  case Increasing:
    std::cerr << "Increasing" << std::endl;
    break;
  case Decreasing:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Though it's not at all clear from the question, I'm pretty sure that this doesn't do what's required. I think the message should be displayed only if `val[i] < val[i+1]` for *all* `i`. This code will print the message provide this is true for *at least one* `i`.

Comment: If one state is saved for the whole algorithm than it will print the last state (which I agree can be incorrect). He can always update the current state by checking the old state 
`state = State::Unknown;`
than in the loop:
`if(state ==  State::Unknown) state = State::Increasing;
else state == State::Other;`